# SQL Server 2017 - Most purchased or occured categories and sub categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL so have few questions.

In my table

[image]

-- PART 1-- Here I have got the cust info based on customer table and joined with Transactions to get the total amount--

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (cust_id),
    DOB,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, Customer.DOB, 103), GETDATE()) AS [Age IN Months],
    Gender,
    city_code,
    (total_amt - (Rate + Tax)) AS [Total_sale_amt] 
FROM    
    Customer 
JOIN 
    Transactions ON Customer.customer_Id = Transactions.cust_id 
ORDER BY 
    [Age IN Months] DESC;
```

-- PART 2 -- Made a Basket Count of Distinct Cust_IDs---- Made a Count of total transactions and unique count of product cat and subcat

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (cust_id) AS [Dist_Cust_ID],
    COUNT(transaction_id) AS [Transaction_Count],
    COUNT(DISTINCT prod_cat_cdoe) AS [Unq_Cat_Count],
    COUNT(DISTINCT prod_subcat_code) AS [Unq_SubCat_Count],
    MAX(tran_date) AS [Last_Trans_Date],
    SUM(Qty) AS Total_Sale_Quantity,
    COUNT(Qty) AS Basket_Count,
    AVG(QTY) AS [Average_Basket_Quant],
    AVG(total_amt) AS Avg_Basket_Amt 
FROM    
    Transactions 
GROUP BY    
    cust_id;
```

Here I intend to add the most purchased categories and sub categories of a customer how do I add that?

I know my table looks messy because I have to add or join the tables after wards but would love to hear a suggestion.

--- My Question is---
--- Add 4 new Categories ---
(
1) Most Purchased Category--
2) Most Purchased Sub Category --
3) Most Purchased Category name--
4) Most Purchased Sub Category name --) for each customer

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: I've gotta ask... Why would you screenshot your code instead of copy/pasting it?

Comment: So that it would be clear but my bad sorry I am adding the code. Thanks !

Comment: @BeyonDIN Understood, but we can't copy/paste it into our SSMS apps and troubleshoot in that case.

Comment: @dfundako - My bad mate I have added the code.

Comment: Stop and think. First, using DISTINCT is a big red flag that something is wrong. Notice in your output for query 1 that customer 266997 has multiple rows. So what is the purpose of DISTINCT? Furthermore, your use of "total amount" is concerning. Did you want a total amount to include all transactions for each customer? That isn't what your query does. Is that why you added DISTINCT to the select statement?

Comment: Yes I wanted to include all transactions for each customer

Comment: I would have thought `customer.DOB` would be stored as type `date`, so not sure why you're doing the `CONVERT` to use it with `DATEDIFF`

Comment: @Richardissimo - I tried doing date diff without convert as I imported the table so I am not sure why date diff doesn't work on the same hence I converted the same and I got the value.